# error: method execute in class AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> cannot be applied to given types

Tags: android, mysql, bitmap, bitmapimage

I'm wanted to send text and image from android to `MySQL` through php. However, I get error and not able to solve.  Can someone help me to figure it out the problem? Thanks a lot

**Add Function**

```
 public void Add(final String claimType, final String Amount, final String Description,  final Bitmap photo)
    {
        class AddImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait",null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
                data.put(Configs.KEY_TYPE,claimType);
                data.put(Configs.KEY_AMOUNT,Amount);
                data.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGEDESCRIPTION,Description);
                String uploadImage=getStringImage(photo);
                data.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE,uploadImage);
                data.put(Configs.KEY_TSID,IDFromInfo);
                RequestHandler rh=new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.ADD_WORKFORCE,data);
                return  result;
            }
        }

        AddImage ru = new AddImage();
        ru.execute(claimType, Amount, Description, photo);  // error
    }
```

**Error**

```
Error:(185, 11) error: method execute in class AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> cannot be applied to given types;
required: Void[]
found: String,String,String,Bitmap
reason: varargs mismatch; String cannot be converted to Void
where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
```

Comment: you are passing wrong parameters in execute method. It should be according to what you have used when extending asynctask

Comment: @VivekMishra  
What is the correct way ?

Comment: instead of passing parameters to asynctask pass them to your ADD method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

```
        public void Add(final String claimType, final String Amount, final String Description,  final Bitmap photo)
        {        
          new AddImage().execute();
        }

       class AddImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait",null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
                data.put(Configs.KEY_TYPE,claimType);
                data.put(Configs.KEY_AMOUNT,Amount);
                data.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGEDESCRIPTION,Description);
                String uploadImage=getStringImage(photo);
                data.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE,uploadImage);
                data.put(Configs.KEY_TSID,IDFromInfo);
                RequestHandler rh=new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.ADD_WORKFORCE,data);
                return  result;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your doInBackground expects you to pass no param (Void... params) and you pass 4 params (claimType, Amount, Description, photo)

Comment: You can create a class with your 4 objects, and declare your AsyncTask like this :  AsyncTask<YourObject, Void, String>. Then call ru.execute(instanceOfyourObject)

Comment: YourObject refer to?

Comment: The new class with your 4 variables

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask` like this :

```
class AddImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

and in doInBackground(String... params) get string's as :

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
            data.put(Configs.KEY_TYPE,params[1]);
            data.put(Configs.KEY_AMOUNT,params[2]);
            data.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGEDESCRIPTION,params[3]);

}
```

Comment: `Error:(186, 11) error: method execute in class AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> cannot be applied to given types;
required: String[]
found: String,String,String,Bitmap
reason: varargs mismatch; Bitmap cannot be converted to String
where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask`